What does "You're up there" mean?
The prospector digs many holes at different spots by
the river to find gold but finds nothing:

Prospector: There's a pocket up there. How far, we don't know.

Then he plants a flag in one of the deeper holes:

Prospector: You're up there.


What does "You're up there" mean?
Here "Pocket" means a large gold vein.

Did you watch the complete movie "All Gold Canyon" or just this bit ?

@JamesMathai   The movie itself is called "The Ballad of Buster Scruggs”, there are several stories involved, the one with the prospector is called "All Gold Canyon". I have been asking the OP to cite their sources but they probably haven't understood. It's in the Wiki link I posted in the comments.

@Mari-LouA I found another link with the help of your link. And the complete dialogue it is clear that the Prospector is addressing the "gold pocket"

Be up there with someone is an
idiom and is informal.  It means

to be equal to someone else in ability or in a particular skill:
As a composer, he was up there with the best.

Cambridge Dictionary
The prospector knows the location of a nearby pocket and is confident of finding the exact spot.

You're up there.

means he is [edited] close enough to the target that this can almost be considered mission accomplished.  This is similar to someone having acquired the ability to be up there with the best.
Edit
Taken literally, the sentence means
You're up there where the gold is.
You're near where the gold is.

You're (the gold) up (further ahead) there (location). The meaning of the phrase is meant to be literal not figurative.

Thanks, @Mari-Lou A.  I've added this point.

Who/what is being referring to when the prospector says "You're up there"? Is he talking about himself or the gold?

You refer to the people.

You refer to the people In the scene the viewer knows there are two people, the prospector and the young man. The prospector is working alone and is unaware of the young man shadowing him, so he is not talking to a team or a group of people.  See this Wikipedia excerpt

Thanks,  @Mari-Lou A.  Ah, now I paid attention to the video in the post.  The prospector is indeed alone.  So he is talking to himself, and you means the prospector himself.  I've changed they are to he is in the paragraph just before my previous edit.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I. Understanding the Prospector's Method :
How did early prospectors know where to mine for gold?.
Early prospectors identified gold by panning sediments in streams, searching for tiny gold particles ("colours") or minerals associated with gold. They followed traces "upstream" knowing that losing the trail meant they’d passed the source. This systematic process involved testing and observing patterns to locate potential gold pockets.
In the movie, "All Gold Canyon", the prospector isn’t randomly digging; he has found evidence suggesting a gold pocket exists nearby. He’s working his way along the riverbank, narrowing down the possible location.
The prospector first planted a flag upstream (perhaps at the last hole he dug). Now, standing downstream near one of the earlier holes, he plants a second flag. By doing this, he’s marking the suspected range within which the gold pocket lies—between the two flags.
II. Meaning of "You're up ("upstream") there"
This phrase follows the earlier statement:

"There's a pocket up ("upstream") there. How far, we don't know."

The prospector doesn’t know the exact location of the pocket but is confident it’s somewhere between the two flags, closer to the upstream one. By saying “You’re up there,” he personifies the gold pocket, expressing determination to find it. It’s a mix of hope, experience, and persistence, showing his belief that success is close.
This idea is reinforced as he continues addressing the gold pocket directly:

"Okay, Mr. Pocket. I’ma coming! I’ma coming. You just sit there, ’cause I’ma coming."

In essence, "You're up there" means "I'm sure you're somewhere between these flags, closer to the upstream one, and I'll find you!"
It’s a statement of confidence and resolve rather than a precise indication of the pocket's location.
III. Why the Prospector keeps talking to himself in the Movie:
These dialogues guide the audience by explaining the prospector's actions and mindset. Without them, the scene might feel unclear or repetitive. Just like a cooking show host explaining each step, the prospector’s words keep viewers engaged and informed.

Edited my answer after seeing the full dialogue: "All Gold Canyon" Mm-hm. Maybe… two.  Oh.  Not a speck.  Ahh.  Let’s go the other way.  Four.  Seven.  Twelve.  Five.  Going down.  Three.  Two.  Back to nothing.  Ha!  Okay.  There’s a pocket up there.  How far, we don’t know.  You’re up there.  Okay, Mr. Pocket.  All right.  I’ma coming!  I’ma coming.  You just sit there, ’cause I’ma coming.  Where are you, Mr. Pocket?  You to the left, to the right, or straight up the middle?  Well, we’ll just have to see, won’t we?  We’ll just have to see.  Goodnight, Mr. Pocket.  Sit tight, Mr. Pocket!
